# Angular JS: angular.copy crashes the browser when an object references another object

Tags: angularjs, deep-copy

I have the following JavaScript/Angular code:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
a.ref = b;
b.ref = a;
angular.copy(a);
```

When `angular.copy` fires, the browser locks up.  I'm assuming this is because the copy function is doing a deep copy, and when it starts to copy a's reference of b, it goes into b and then wants to copy its reference of a, thus creating a circular copy, which will never end.

Is this assumption right?  If so, is there a way to avoid this?  I'm assuming the answer will involve changing the way my data looks, but I'm curious to hear another person's thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right, the problem is the circular reference. `JSON.stringify` will also complain about this structure.  `jQuery.extend` detects circular references at a very basic level and can handle your basic example here, but [jQuery.extend has its own issues as well](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12227).  If you're already using jQuery, you can just use extend, but otherwise you may want to look at writing something yourself, or you can use this fancy `cloneObject` function I found via Google:

https://gist.github.com/NV/1396086

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for clearing up my assumption.  Sounds like the structure of my data should just be changed...

Comment: Is that how you fixed it? Were you able to get it working with a circular reference?

Comment: We fixed it by reworking our data model.  Instead of giving the child node the actual parent object, we added a child node and parent node ID to each child... so when we go to create grandchildren, it's easy to pass along its parent's ID.

Answer (score 1):

`_.cloneDeep` handles circular references. http://lodash.com/